# Leaking freight car problem - Help understanding a solution

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, mass, acceleration

I'm dealing with the leaking freight car problem:

> A freight car is loaded with a water tank. The mass of the freight car and the filled water tank is from the start $m_0$. At time $t=0$ a horisontal force $\vec{F}$ starts pushing the freight car and at the same time a water tap is opened in the bottom of the freight car so that a constant mass of water per unit of time $k= \left|\dfrac{dm}{dt} \right|$ is leaking out.
> Assume that $\vec{F}$ is constant, $\vec{F} = F_0\hat{x}$. **Determine the freight car's acceleration**.

## The given solution

> The force equation $\vec{F} = \dot{\vec{p}} \implies F_0\hat{x} = \dot{p}_x\hat{x} \implies p_x\hat{x} = (F_0t + C)\hat{x}$
> $\vec{v}(t=0) = 0 \implies \vec{p}(t=0) = 0 \implies C = 0 \implies p_x\hat{x} = F_0t\hat{x}$
> $\hat{x}\text{-direction}: p_x = mv_x = F_0t \implies v_x(t) = \dfrac{F_0t}{m(t)}$
> $$a_x(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt}v_x(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left ( \dfrac{F_0 t}{m(t)} \right) = F_0 \dfrac{m(t) - t\dot{m}(t)}{m^2(t)} = F_0\dfrac{m_0 - kt + tk}{m^2(t)} = \dfrac{F_0}{m_0}\dfrac{1}{\left(1-\frac{k}{m_0}t \right)^2}$$

Clearly this solution differs from my own solution. I cannot really see anything wrong with it, but on the other hand I don't see anything wrong with my own solution either. I do remember reading from Kleppner and Kolenkow that one cannot apply the equation $\vec{p} = m\vec{v}$ blindly to a system of many particles, so maybe there's something going on there. **I wonder which solution is correct and what is wrong in either one?**

---

## My solution

Usually I've seen this problem framed in terms of sand but the principle should be the same. My reasoning is similar to the one presented for example in [these notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/readings/MIT8_01F16_chapter12.1_12.3.pdf) (p. 12-5 to 12-7).

Since the motion is one dimensional, I'll write $P(t)$ instead of $\vec{P}(t)$ etc. I imagine that at time $t$, the freight car (including the water tank) has mass $m_c(t) = m_0 - kt$ and the velocity $v_c(t)$ so that the momentum of the freight car at time $t$ is
$$ P(t) = m_c(t)v_c(t) $$
Next consider time $t+\Delta t$. During $\Delta t$, the velocity of the freight car has changed to $v_c(t) + \Delta v_c$. Water of mass $\Delta m_w$ has leaked out were we estimate its velocity to also be $v_c(t) + \Delta v_c$. The freight cars mass is $m_c(t) - \Delta m_w$.  The momentum of the freight car and the leaked water (the same system as at time $t$) is therefore
$$P(t + \Delta t) = (m_c(t) - \Delta m_w + \Delta m_w)[v_c(t) + \Delta v_c] = m_c(t)[v_c(t) + \Delta v_c]$$

Therefore $\Delta P = P(t + \Delta t) - P(t) = m_c(t)\Delta v_c$ so that
$$F_0 = \dot{P}(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \dfrac{\Delta P}{\Delta t} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \dfrac{m_c(t)\Delta v_c}{\Delta t} = m_c(t)\dot{v_c}(t)$$
So that the acceleration $\dot{v_c}(t)$ is given by
$$\dot{v_c}(t) = \dfrac{F_0}{m_c(t)} = \dfrac{F_0}{m_0 - kt}$$
Provided $t \leq \dfrac{m_{w_0}}{k}$ where $m_{w_0}$ is the initial mass of the water in the full tank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seems right, but complicated

$$F=ma$$ can be used, and at any particular time $m=m_0-kt$, so
$$a=\frac{F_0}{m_0-kt}$$

In the given solution, this seems wrong $$v_x(t) = \dfrac{F_0t}{m(t)}$$
it seems to be saying that all the impulse provided by the force goes into the motion of the mass that is left, the $m(t)$.  However some of the impulse also went into motion of water that later leaked out.  That's probably why the two answers are different.

Comment: Oh, right. That's way simpler haha. Thanks!

Comment: @ DancingIceCream  Glad it helped, all the best.

Comment: In this problem, m(t) = $m_o$ - kt. You cannot say that v(t) = a(t) t.

Comment: @ R.W. Bird the question was to find the acceleration,  the above wasn't used